# Iterate Through a File and Add Information to String Array - C

Tags: c

I'm trying to iterate through a couple files and put the information on each line into a dynamically allocated string array. I allocated the arrays like this:

```
followerArr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (followerCount + 1));
for (i = 0; i < followerCount; i++)
    followerArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
```

Which seems to work completely fine. Then I went through the file until reaching the end of the file and wanted to put the names of users into tha string array. One of the files looked like this:

```
4
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

Where the first number is the number of users in the file, in this case 4. My code for the file scanning is this:

```
if (followerCount > 0) {
    fp3 = fopen(followerFile, "r");
    if (fp3 == NULL)
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    else {
        char line[1000];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp3) != NULL) {
            if (i > 0)
                followerArr[i - 1] = line;
            i++;
        }
        fclose(fp3);
    }
}
```

I also did a print statement in the while loop and it printed out normally, ie it would print

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

But after the while loop and closing the file, it prints out user4 all 4 times. Why is the array basically changing itself from the time it's in the while loop and then once it's outside it?

Comment: Strings in C do not support your assignment `followerArr[i - 1] = line`. Essentially, you are copying the same data in all of your array elements. You can see that if you print the lines in your loop *after* the assignment (and from the array).

Comment: Alright that would make sense because it works in the while loop but not after. How could I fix it so that the data is written properly to the array?

Comment: You are leaking memory too.  You've allocated memory assigning to `followerArr[i]` then you overwrite the value. Instead use `strncpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just give you another example of reading a file line by line and maybe it will help you with your current code.

```
char* line;
ssize_t len;
char** dest = malloc (sizeof(char*) * 15)
size_t read = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; // Remove the newline
    dest[i] = malloc (strlen(line));
    strcpy(dest[i], line);
}
```

Afterward your going to need to free each element and the entire array